# setting canvas size to fill the body is adding scrollbars to the window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the width/height of a canvas element to fill the container it is in. Currently it works, but when it fills the body, scrollbars are added.

```
let masterCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let parent = masterCanvas.parentElement;
masterCanvas.width = parent.offsetWidth;
masterCanvas.height = parent.offsetHeight;
```

I have the following styles:

```
<style>
    body, html { padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
</style>
```

And the following body:

```
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/ynkcfsud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas element behaves like an image, so it is an inline element. You'll need to apply `display: block` to the canvas.

Comment: PS: it took me some time to catch this one :)

Comment: That was it! I didn't know that something like that would cause this. Thanks!